# Action Filter Executing Recursively in .Net Mvc C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes, attributes, action-filter

I have a custom Action filter used to authenticate user by checking its cookie then sending cookie to the server and get response about either user exist or not using web api call.

I have decorated my controller with that Action filter like this:

**Admin Controller**

```
[CheckuserAuthenticateelseRedirect]

public class AdminController : Controller
{
//All actions goes here
}
```

and here is the Action filter class inside Model

**Action Filter**

```
 public class CheckuserAuthenticateelseRedirect: System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
 {
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        var userCokiesData = getUserCokiesData();
        if (userCokiesData==null)
        {



            var controller = (AdministratorBlog.Controllers.AdminController)filterContext.Controller;
            filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("login", "Admin");

        }
        else
        {
            var userdata = getuserDateByEmail(userCokiesData.username, 3, WebSiteID);
            if (userdata==null)
            {

            var controller = (AdministratorBlog.Controllers.AdminController)filterContext.Controller;
            filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("login", "Admin");


            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);


    }

  private UsersTB getuserDateByEmail(string email, int userTypeId, int siteid)
  {
       //return User if exist else null
  }
   private getCookiesModel getUserCokiesData()
   {
    //read  cookies
   }
}
```

**Problem**

When the request is made, the Actionfilter executes and if cookie is null it send request to login view but before returning view **"OnActionExecuting"** method called again and again, the result is no response.Please help what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have applied filter `CheckuserAuthenticateelseRedirect` to complete controller so when a user without cookies hits action sends it to `Login` action on which again same filter is used, which makes the call to `OnActionExecuting` recursive.

**The fix** would be that you should stop binding your `Login` action to the filter because unauth users will be hitting it and they will never have the cookie.